# Android FirebaseUI: Signing in with another Google account is troublesome

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm currently checking out the FirebaseUI offering for Firebase Authentication, and am having some issues while playing around with it a bit.

The first sign-in I made with Email/Password, where I used a Gmail address and a custom password (no Google Sign-In), and was surprised that this worked so well.

I later then used Google Sign-In from FirebaseUI with the same address, and it got "upgraded" to Google Sign-In just as expected. Further attempts to sign in with that address via the Email/Password button got rerouted internally to Google Sign-In, so that the initial password was obsolete and none was required at all, as is the case with Google Sign-In. This was also somewhat expected and can be desirable.

Here comes the problem: Now, whenever I am signed out and want to sign in via Google Sign-In in FirebaseUI with ANOTHER Gmail address, I can't do so, because I am no longer asked to select an email address which is known to the device (initially all three Gmail addresses which are registered on the phone were shown). It always signs in with the first address I used.

How can I indicate FirebaseUI that when the user clicks on Google Sign-In, the email address selection dialog should ALWAYS be shown?

This is the code I'm using
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui#sign_in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#sign-out):

> ### Sign out
>
> With the integrations provided by AuthUI, signing out a user is a
>   multi-stage process:
>
> 1. The user must be signed out of the FirebaseAuth instance.
> 2. Smart Lock for Passwords must be instructed to disable automatic sign-in, in order to prevent an automatic sign-in loop that prevents
>      the user from switching accounts.
> 3. If the current user signed in using either Google or Facebook, the user must also be signed out using the associated API for that
>      authentication method. This typically ensures that the user will not
>      be automatically signed-in using the current account when using that
>      authentication method again from the authentication method picker,
>      which would also prevent the user from switching between accounts on
>      the same provider.
>
> In order to make this process easier, AuthUI provides a simple signOut
>   method to encapsulate this behavior. The method returns a Task which
>   is marked completed once all necessary sign-out operations are
>   completed:
>
> ```
> AuthUI.getInstance()
>     .signOut(this)
>     .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
>         public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
>             // user is now signed out
>             startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, SignInActivity.class));
>             finish();
>         }
>     });
> ```