# Firebase google auth won't let me choose the account to connect with

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I have implemented Firebase Auth into my app to let my users connect with their Google accounts. So far so good, however once a user has chosen to connect with a specific account from the google account chooser popup, he won't be able to choose a different account the next time he logs in. The previously selected account will be automatically picked for the authentication.

I really don't find this behavior correct, so I am trying to fix it.
After some research I found that I can use `setCustomParameters(prompt: "select_account")` with the `googleProvider`, like so:

```
this.googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
this.googleProvider.setCustomParameters({
   prompt: "select_account",
});
```

More info here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#authenticationuriparameters

In my case, using the `consent` and `select_account` parameters don't seem to have any impact, the user does not get to choose which account to use.

Edit: It would seem that it works correctly with chrome, but not with firefox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the source of the issue, it is in fact not really an issue. The google account picker will only show up if you have other accounts registered onto the device/browser you are **currently** using. If you want to choose a different account that is not saved into your device/browser, you would first need to log into it via google.

Comment: So the first time I logged in it allowed me to type. my email address and sign into my account. 

I then sign out, how do I pick to sign into another account? Right now its just signing me back into the first account.

Comment: @TenDigitGrid https://stackoverflow.com/a/59220616/18716297

Answer (score 1):

Same issue. It's correct after adding

```
provider.setCustomParameters({
    prompt: "select_account"
})
```

Comment: It would be better to add a clarification about how this works.

Answer (score 1):

Add this into your `googleProvider` and you'll see the popup:

```
const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
googleProvider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).